# How to get the value of a parameter in Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to get the value of a parameter from a GET endpoint of:

```
/api/image/id
```

The file structure is:

```
src/app/api/image/[id]/route.ts
```

And when I'm trying to retrieve the id parameter, this results in `null`.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
  return NextResponse.json({ id }, { status: 200 }); // { "id": null }
```

I think this is something related to the folder structure. But I can't find a proper folder structure for this.

Thanks in advance!

I tried renaming route.ts to [id].ts, and moving route.ts inside just in the image folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found that in Next.js 13.2+, the second parameter of the GET request is where developers find the parameters.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

                                                // ⬇️ Here is the `params` property
export async function GET(request: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string } } ) {

  return NextResponse.json({ id: params.id }, { status: 200 });

}
```

I've tried unsuccessfully to get it from the request object. Maybe in the future it will change since it is an early version.

Comment: I've try but I've got
Argument type {status: number} is not assignable to parameter type ResponseInit | undefined

Comment: @DeyanVatsov It's because `status` is not a property of the second parameter Response. Using `params.status` in the function body should work once you declase `{ params }` in the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve information from a URL, you can utilize the optional second parameter of the [router handler](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers) known as [context (documentation)](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional).

For instance, let's assume your URL is:

```yaml
https://example.com/api/users/1
```

You can access its parameter value by using `context.params.userId` as shown in the example below:

```js
export async function GET(request, context) {
  const userId = context.params.userId; // '1'
}
```

This code was tested with the following configuration:

```
// package.json
{
  "next": "13.2.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw in Next.js documentation this:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  return <div>My Post: {params.slug}</div>
}
```